# Substract in Smarty PHP and keep decimals

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

in Prestashop 1.6 i am trying in a section of my site to appear the result of a substraction of a stable number (59) with the total of cart.
My difficulty is that i need, when the total of the cart is not rounded, and i.e. is 39.90, to get the result as is, aka 19.10 and not 20 as it does.

So i have already try with the following codes but i still need help to improve it and to fix it finally.

```
{math equation=(59-$total) format="%.2f"}
{convertPrice price=(59-$total) format="%.2f"}
{convertPrice price=(59-$total)}
```

None of the above works as i want...
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
{$yourNumber|round:"2"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, maybe you don't understand...
I don't want to round the final result but i want it as it is exactly with decimals.